# Deriving $\frac{q}{r} \times p(q, r) = P(q-1, r)- P(q-1, r+1) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I want to derive why this equation is true.

$$\frac{q}{r} \times p(q, r) = P(q-1, r)- P(q-1, r+1) $$

, where

$$p(q, r) = \frac{r(r+1)(r+2)\dots(r+q-1)}{q!}p^q(1-p)^r$$,

$$P(q-1, r) = \sum_{x=0}^{q-1} \frac{r(r+1)(r+2)\dots(r+x-1)}{x!}p^x(1-p)^{r}$$

$$P(q-1, r+1) = \sum_{x=0}^{q-1} \frac{(r+1)(r+2)\dots(r+x)}{x!}p^x(1-p)^{r+1}$$

I've been looking at it for a while, but I don't seem to get it.

I started off writing the equation as:

$$\frac{(r+1)(r+2)\dots(r+q-1)}{(q-1)!}p^q(1-p)^r = \sum_{x=0}^{q-1} \frac{r(r+1)(r+2)\dots(r+x-1)}{x!}p^x(1-p)^{r}-\sum_{x=0}^{q-1} \frac{(r+1)(r+2)\dots(r+x)}{x!}p^x(1-p)^{r+1}$$

But I am not getting any further besides endlessly manipulating things, but that doesn't brought success.

Any hints are welcome!

Comment: Is the problem stated correctly?

Comment: I checked it numerically so to my knowledge, yes. Edit: I did make a mistake, corrected it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an algebraic answer (I prefer the combinatorial one, but this may be more helpful for your purpose).
First, remove the common factor of $(1-p)^r$ from all the sums. Then $P(q-1, r+1)$ becomes $$\sum_{x=0}^{q-1}\dfrac{(r+x)!}{r!x!}p^x- \sum_{x=0}^{q-1}\dfrac{(r+x)!}{r!x!}p^{x+1}.$$ Shift the index in the second sum, to get $$\sum_{x=0}^{q-1}\dfrac{(r+x)!}{r!x!}p^x- \sum_{x=1}^{q}\dfrac{(r+x-1)!}{r!(x-1)!}p^{x}$$ and the difference $P(q-1,r) - P(q-1, r+1)$ becomes $$\sum_{x=0}^{q-1}\dfrac{(r+x-1)!}{(r-1)!x!}p^x-\sum_{x=0}^{q-1}\dfrac{(r+x)!}{r!x!}p^x + \sum_{x=1}^{q}\dfrac{(r+x-1)!}{r!(x-1)!}p^{x}.$$ But $\dfrac{(r+x-1)!}{(r-1)!x!}+ \dfrac{(r+x-1)!}{r!(x-1)!}=\dfrac{(r+x)!}{r!x!}$ (Pascal's triangle identity), so the sums from $1$ to $q-1$ cancel out, and you are left with the $x=0$ terms of the first two, and the $x=q$ term of the last, giving $$1 - 1+\dfrac{(r+q-1)!}{r!(q-1)!}p^q,$$ which is just what you want.

Comment: But $P(q-1, r+1)$ has $p^x(1-p)^{r+1}$ and not $p^{x+1}(1-p)^r$ ?

Comment: But that's what you need: divide by $(1-p)^r$ and you are left with $p^x(1-p)=p^x-p^{x+1}$, as in my first displayed equation.

Comment: ah yes, correct!

Comment: I do think that the end result should be $1−1+\frac{(r+q-1)!}{r!(q−1)!}p^q$, right? If we look at the third term of the sum

Comment: Yes, I agree: amended.

Answer (score 1):

If you repeatedly toss a coin with a probability $p$ of Head, then $P(q-1,r)$ is the probability that the $r^{th}$ Tail occurs on or before the $(r+q-1)^{th}$ toss and $P(q-1,r+1)$ is the probability that the $(r+1)^{th}$ Tail occurs on or before the $(r+q)^{th}$ toss. Because the latter event is a subset of the former, the difference between them is the probability that exactly $r$ Tails occur up to and including the $(r+q-1)^{th}$ toss, and the $(r+q)^{th}$ toss is a Head, which is $\dfrac{q}{r}p(q,r)$.

Comment: Wait. Did you mean q/r instead of q/p?

Comment: Yes; thank you. Amended.

Comment: The probability that the $^{ℎ}$ Tail occurring on or before the $(+−1)^{ℎ}$ toss is the same as saying we need $r$ tails in $r+q-1$ tosses and this probability does not involved a summation. @mcd can you please clarify? Thanks. OP - can you give me the source of the problem? Thanks

Comment: Well, @sku, the probability of the $r^{th}$ Tail occurring on or before the $(r+q−1)^{th}$ toss is the same as saying we need at least $r$ Tails in $r+q−1$ tosses, not exactly $r$ Tails.

Comment: @mcd I think it would help the answer if you prove it formally…